# Trying to convert Manual JSON to Class Object process to Automatic

Tags: android-studio

**Sample JSON Data**

```
{
  "Status": true,
  "Message": "Roles retrieved successfully",
  "Data": [
    {
      "Role": "SuperAdmin",
    },
    {
      "Role": "Admin",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Role Class**

```
public class Role {
    public int  Role;

    public int getRole() {
        return Role;
    }

    public void setRoleID(String role) {
        Role = role;
    }

}
```

**Json Data Equivalent class**

```
public class RoleData {
    public String Message;
    public boolean Status;
    public List<Role> Data;


    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Message = message;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public List<Role> getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Role> data) {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

**Below is my code to parse the retrieved JSON Data into class object of type RoleData**

```
private void parseJsonResponse(String responsestring) throws JSONException {

    RoleData roleData = new RoleData();
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responsestring);
    if ((response == null) || response.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    try {

        if (response.getBoolean("Status")) {
            JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("Data");
            List<Role> temp = new ArrayList<Role>();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject dataObj = data.getJSONObject(i);
                Role role = new Role();
                role.setRole(dataObj.getString("Role"));
                roleData.setMessage(response.getString("Message"));
                roleData.setStatus(response.getBoolean("Status"));
                temp.add(role);
            }
            roleData.setData(temp);
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is there any better way to avoid above writing the parsing code? In .NET we can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method which converts JSON into class object like below.

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoleData>(JSON_Response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout this libraries:

https://github.com/google/gson

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson (supports json very well)

https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

both are based on annotation to configure the variables that do NOT match with the name in the json, normally they are not required :)

Comment: I am using Android Studio. Can you share the guidelines about the installation of https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson  ?